# Form doesn't post without backslash at the end of action url

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Today i faced this strange problem and it's blowing my mind because i have no idea why is this happening,i have a form with this action `http://localhost/wp/` but it doesn't work without the backslash at the end , i mean when the action is `http://localhost/wp` it doesn't work , 
let me show you with example :

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="example">
</form>

<?php
      var_dump( $_POST ); // will output an empty array
?>
```

but now we add a `"/"` to the end of action url it works, but i want it to work in both ways because i'm designing this website for a customer.

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="example">
</form>

<?php
      var_dump( $_POST ); // will output array( "example" => "XXXX" )
?>
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong please!!

:: it's wordpress installed on XAMPP - Windows 8.1

Comment: check your htaccess rewrite rules

Comment: Additional helpful info: Is it wordpress?  A PHP Framework like Zend or Symphony? etc., because the issue is likely with the router and how it parses the URI.  Adding those details to the question and to your tags will help get the right people here to answer.

Comment: had same problem, in my case  form was inside a div tag with id, when I removed those id, then it works.

Comment: @kevinNelson Thank you i added the informations , yes it's wordpress ,

Comment: @Amir when i only put the form in my theme's 'index.php' problem still exists

Comment: @RamRaider .htaccess file is empty only these comments are in it `# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `http://localhost/wp/, this will execute any Apache default file in the directory /path/to/localhost/wp/. For example in the WordPress case index.php.

When you use `http://localhost/wp`, it is telling Apache to execute the file wp in the directory /path/to/localhost/.

So the two cases ask for two different things, with different results.

If you always want to run WordPress, modify your .htaccess file to always go to /localhost/wp/, even if the user didn't add the slash.

Comment: is there anything i can do to make sure that the customer won't face the problem i faced on his/her online website?

Comment: From your directory structure, it sounds like you might be running your WordPress installation from a subdirectory. If so, you might want to look at  http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory, which uses a slightly different approach.

Comment: FYI - "so the two cases ask for two different things..." is not accurate.  When I go to `http://localhost/_test` without the trailing slash, Apache returns the file `/_test/index.php`. It has no problem figuring this out.  The only thing that can mess this up is misconfigured .htaccess rules or the PHP router not properly handling the URI.

Comment: @Kevin Nelson - that's actually not base Apache but a feature of mod_dir, which, if there is a not found, can test with the same URL and a slash added. Whether it does this is determined by a configuration variable DirectorySlash (which defaults to On).

Comment: @bobdye, interesting...learn something new every day.  Thanks.  Are there any servers in existence without it, though?  Because in over 10 years, and a dozen or more servers, I've never been required to add the slash.

Comment: I don't know. I think that you are right in that every default install I've ever seen has included mod_dir as an active module, probably for these types of situations.